Proof of $f(\overline{S}) = \overline{f(S)}$
I know that $f(\overline{S}) = \overline{f(S)}$ if and only if $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is an homeomorphism, you can find a proof here.
I am trying to establish a proof of the $\impliedby$ part, but I don't know whether it is correct or I am missing something.
$$f(\overline{S}) = f(\cap_{S \subseteq E \subseteq X, \, E \, closed} E) = \cap_{S \subseteq E \subseteq X, \, E \, closed} f(E) = \cap_{E \subseteq Y \mid S \subseteq f^{-1}(E) \subseteq X, \, f^{-1}(E) \, closed} E = \cap_{E \subseteq Y closed \mid S \subseteq f^{-1}(E) \subseteq X} E = \cap_{S \subseteq E \subseteq Y, \, E \, closed} E = \overline{f(S)}$$
where the first equality is one of the definition of closure; the second that functions and intersections can be exchanged; the third is renaming $E$ to $f^{-1}(E)$, and up to now I think I only used, in the third equality, that $f$ is a bijection, but not the continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ yet. Then, in the fourth equality the continuity of $f$ is used to get that if $E$ is closed then $f^{-1}(E)$ is closed, and the continuity of $f^{-1}$ is used to have that if $f^{-1}(E)$ is closed, then $E$ is closed. To conclude, the fifth equality is just rewriting the condition applying $f$, and the last the definition of closure.
I am not particularly confident about my reasoning for the third and fourth inequality, somehow I am always confused by changing variables in summations, intersections, etc. Are my steps correct? Or what am I missing?

I think there's something wrong with your reasoning. To begin with, unless $Y=X$ you cannot have $E \subset X$ and $f^{-1}(E) \subset X$ as well.

@Oscar I don't think I have done it in my proof, if you think I did, could you specify in which step?

Note that, a map $g:X \to Y$ is continuous if and only if $g(\overline{E}) \subseteq \overline{g(E)}$ for any subset $E \subseteq X$. You can see a proof of this here.
With this in mind, note that, by definition, if $f$ is a homeomorphism, then $f$ and $f^{-1}$  are both continuous. This means we can apply the aforementioned result to conclude that
$$\forall \ A \subseteq X, \ f(\overline{A}) \subseteq \overline{f(A)} \quad \text{and} \quad \forall B \subset Y, \ f^{-1}(\overline{B}) \subseteq \overline{f^{-1}(B)}. \ \ (\dagger)$$
Particularly, if we fix an arbitrary $S\subseteq X$, then
$$f(\overline{S}) \subseteq \overline{f(S)} \quad \text{and} \quad \overline{f(S)} = f(f^{-1}\big(\overline{f(S)}\big)) \subseteq f\big(\overline{f^{-1}(f(S))} \big) = f(\overline{S}),$$
where the second inclusion follows by setting $B = \overline{f(S)}$ and using $(\dagger)$.

This is the proof I linked.
